# Is a mixed/ random effects model required if fixed effects model shows no pattern in the residuals?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, mixed-model, effects

I've got some data on discrete flood events (response variable - duration) on several rivers.

I've modelled the response variable by site and time using a Generalized Linear Model:

```
 mod = glm(duration ~ site + time)
```

I've then looked at the residual plots and cannot find any evidence for temporal correlation in the residuals. Does this mean that this model approach is valid (and that using a mixed/ random effects model is unnecessary) (or should one always use mixed/ random effects models for time-series data)?

Any links to reading references regarding this subject would be brilliant,

Comment: for what it's worth, this is really just a linear model (`lm` in R); since you're not specifying `family`, it defaults to Gaussian family.  Technically you're right that it's a generalized linear model (since linear models are a subset of GLMs) but it may muddy the waters slightly.

Comment: I think you are somewhat equating Linear Mixed Effects models with Generalized Linear models and that also is a bit "odd"... Reference-wise: Stroup's "GLMM" (2013), Chapt. 2 "Design Matters" might be nice starting point. In general, as Pinheiro & Bates (2000) Chapt. 2 "LME model formulation" state: "*(LME m.) extend linear models by incorporating random effects which can be regarded as additional error terms to account for correlation among observations within the group*"; assuming you do not have such a grouping structure... well, you don't really need an LME, do you? :)

Comment: Maybe I was a bit over-simplifying with me previous comment. Do you have any design related reasons to expect such a structure? If yes, maybe you could include it and probably investigate why it comes up so weak (it will also keep reviewers happy). Otherwise if nothing comes up I do not realistically see a reason to have an LME (or a GLMM for that matter).